# Can I get the naturalWidth of the img in a picture-element?

Tags: javascript, html

`el.naturalWidth` should return the width of an image. When I make a picture-element like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('original'))
console.log(document.getElementById('original').naturalWidth)
```

```html
    <picture>
    <source srcSet='http://placehold.it/350x350' id='alt' media='(max-width: 50000px)' />
    <img src='http://placehold.it/500x500' id="original" />
</picture>
```

and run it on a small screen, it outputs the right element, but the width of the source-image, why? and what can I do about it?

Comment: That's what `naturalWidth` means: its the width of the **source** image.  If you want the element width, use another width attribute.  Such as "width", "clientWidth", or "scrollWidth"

Comment: try to not target the img-tag, instead try the picture-tag. Had a similar problem with picture tags. Maybe it helps

Comment: @Sysix but I want the size of the picture, not the image...

Answer (score 0):

Not clear based only on the code provided, but try to make sure the image has been loaded. An example as below:

HTML

```
<picture>
    <source srcSet='http://placehold.it/350x350' id='alt' media='(max-width: 50000px)' />
    <img id="original" />
</picture>
```

JS

```
var img_obj = new Image();
img_obj.src = 'http://placehold.it/500x500';
img_obj.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('original').src = img_obj.src;
  console.log(img_obj.naturalWidth);
  console.log(document.getElementById('original').getBoundingClientRect().width)
};
```

Also try `document.getElementById('original').getBoundingClientRect().width` for the width of the `<img>` element.